# How is state being updated?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
constructor() {
   super();
     this.state = {
        lists: [], 
        items: {}              
   };
}

handleAddList(s) {      
    var temp= this.state.lists.slice(0,this.state.lists.length);
    temp.push(s);

    console.log(this.state.items);

       this.setState({lists: temp},function(){

          var ourList = this.state.items;
          ourList[s] = [];

          console.log(this.state.items);

          // var items = Object.assign({}, this.state.items, {[s]: []})

         // this.setState( { items: items } );
       });
}
```

the first console.log shows items is null.  The second console.log shows items updated with the value of s as the key and an empty array as the value.  How is items being updated?

So, it must be that this assignment is by reference:

```
var ourList = this.state.items;
ourList[s] = [];
```

Does that mean it's ok to setState this way?

I'm trying to follow a course on react, if someone could point me to a source where this is covered I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any modification in array will not get updated in state unless you use `setState` method of React. The best place to learn react js is documentation [React Get Started](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html).